getUserMedia() and webRTC, modify the buffer before sending
I've tried researching this on my own, but fell short.
Let's say I use getUserMedia() and webRTC to make video calls. Is it possible to hook between the getUserMedia() and webRTC and modify the buffer before it is sent?
Simplest example: Sender base64 encodes the buffer before sending it, receiver decodes it and sending and receiving software is none the wiser that that is happening in the background?

You can make it with WebRTC Encoded Transform.
Here is an official example of End-to-End Encryption.

Oh wow, I wasn't aware this exists. I will look into it, even though it does not seem to be supported yet?

I will accept this as this seems like the proper way to hook into it, even though it still has ways to go before it gets accepted as a standard.
